# How to enable the pathlib.Path autocompletion in VSCode editor?

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, intellisense, pathlib

I have noticed a beautiful new feature in the python interactive window when using pathlib.Path objects:

[image: screenshot showing code cwd = Path.cwd() and autocompletion in the next line when typing cwd / ""]

Intellisense actually shows the content of the directory when typing a slash behind a folder Path. This is awesome! I would like to take advantage of this feature in the file editor too. Is there a way to activate it, or is this only possible in the interactive window's context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a requirement for new functions.There is no way to get prompt in`.py` file at present.I submitted it in [GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/19616) and look forward to their reply.

Of course, you can also try to use **jupyter notebook** to write code, which is the same as the interactive window:

[image]